# Consuming Amazon SQS (AMQP) from Azure

Tags: azure, message-queue, amqp, amazon-sqs, azure-servicebus-queues

The need has come in which we have to consume data coming from a 3rd party in which they have an Amazon SQS instance setup on top of the AMQP protocol. They have given us the following:

1. queue name
2. user name
3. password
4. port
5. virtualhost
6. host

We are a cloud-born company in which we host everything in the Azure cloud, e.g. web services, web apps, databases, etc.

I would like to find out the following:

1. What "service" should I design or develop on from Azure that can consume messages from an Amazon SQS?
2. If Azure Service Bus supports AMQP 1.0 and Amazon SQS supports AMQP 0.9.3, can this be a plausible path?

I guess my question is more related on how to architect my solution.  I know there are frameworks like RabbitMQ, but would like to avoid the VM path.  If solutions like RabbitMQ are the way to go, can only the "consumer" pieces be utilized and not the "server" pieces of RabbitMQ implemented?

Any and all advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SQS does not support AMQP. There are wrapper frameworks. which may allow you consuming messages like you do with a queue service which supports AMQP. Is consuming from the queue directly an option?

Comment: Please clarify with your 3rd party.  Because AWS SQS is a services, it is NOT an instance like EC2, SQS has specific API call : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequestsArticle.html 
 On the other hand, one can setup EC2 instance and load AMQP like rabbitmq , etc.